# How to install and configure Nginx + Gunicorn + Daphane websocket server on amazon linux2 machine?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

How to install and configure websocket in your application on amazon linux2?

I want to configure websocket communication between  Nginx + Gunicorn + Daphane websocker server.

I want to pass my websocket traffic via nginx in amazon linux2

Answer (score 0):

```
Step1.
1.Install the Nginx proxy server in amazon linux2 machine.
command : sudo yum update
command : sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1 
command : sudo systemctl start nginx
command : sudo systemctl status nginx

Step2.
1.Install the Gunicorn Web server in amazon linux2 machine.
Go to the your project directory --> Activate the virtual Environment --> then install the gunicorn web server
command :  pip install gunicorn

Step3.
1.Install the Daphane Websocket server in amazon linux2 machine.
Go to the your project directory --> Activate the virtual Environment -> then install the daphane websocket server.
command : pip install daphane


Step4.
1.Create the systemd service file of Gunicorn.

Example: Gunicorn.service
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/projectnamefolder/projectdirectory
ExecStart=/var/www/projectnamefolder/virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers=5 --log-file=/var/log/gunicorn/access.log --threads=15 applicationname.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------



Step5.
1.Create the systemd service file of Daphane websocket.
Example :  Daphane.service

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[Unit]
Description=WebSocket Daphne Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/projectnamefolder/projectdirectory
ExecStart=/var/www/projectnamefolder/virtualenv/bin/daphne -b :: -p 90901 applicationname.asgi:application
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Step6.
1.This is very Important to pass the internet traffic via nginx proxy.
2.Configuration of Nginx Proxy server in amazon linux2 machine.

GO to the the /etc/nginx/ path and then backup the existing nginx.conf file and then edit the nginx.conf via VI command and then put the following example inside of the nginx.conf file.

Note:  you can overwrite this syntax in your existing nginx.conf in amazon linux2 but before tale the backup of your original file.

Example :

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name public ip address of the server;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /static {
       root /static css files path here; 
           expires 30d;
    }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
    server_name public ip address of the server;
    keepalive_timeout 70;   
    
    ssl_certificate /file path of the ssl certificate;
    ssl_certificate_key /file path of the ssl certificate key file;       

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location = /static/ {
           alias /static css files path here;
    }

        location / {
           proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
           proxy_connect_timeout   1600;
           proxy_send_timeout      1600;
           proxy_read_timeout      1600;

        }

        location ^~ /ws/ {
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; 
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:90901;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

       }

    }

                
#    server {
#        listen       80 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

#        location / {
#        }

#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }

#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/serverkey";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        location / {
#        }
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#            location = /40x.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#            location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Step7.
1.Validate the Nginx.conf file using the command.
command :  nginx -t

you will get the result of the nginx.conf file.

Step8.
1.Restart the all three service.
command :  systemctl restart nginx
command : systemctl restart gunicorn
command : systemctl restart daphane

It should be the work your application via dapahe websocket service.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What details you want?